# Teams DevOps Connector - Client secret is expired

Tags: devops, microsoft-teams, connector

I set up the Azure DevOps connector for a Teams channel that I am an Owner on. It's been working fine but now I need to tweak some settings as I don't want it announcing Canceled Deployments. So I open Connectors, Configured, AzureDevops, expand the "6 Configured" and click Manage.... Or if I just click "Configure" to set up a new one... then i get a new screen with the configuration options.

It shows my account in the dropdown, has an option to add a new account, but shows the error:

```
Failed to acquire an access token.{"Error":"invalid_request","ErrorDescription":"Client secret is expired."}
```

So the only thing I can do is add a new account, I click that and I get a Teams popup, I sign in with my account again, it asks me if I want to stay signed in, sure, popup closes and I'm back on the configuration screen. Still my account in the dropdown, still that error... If I close it and start over no change...
Have signed out of Teams and back in, no luck.

Same error in both the Windows Client (Version 1.3.00.26064 (64-bit)) and the web browser client.
My organization uses O365/Devops.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I think there may be an error on Azure's end. Had the same issue and found this: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1239563/azure-devops-connector-in-ms-teams-yields-a-client.html